# How to remove hidden points from point cloud using normal vectors (in matlab)?

Tags: c++, matlab, hidden, points

I have text file with point cloud data. 
This document contains six columns: **x,y,z coordinates of points and nx,ny, nz** - normal vector coordinate i.e.,

```
-2.27535 2.33442 12.8694 0.492013 -0.866115 -0.0881364
```

Could anyone tell me how can I remove hidden points (which are located in the back surface or  are not visible in the view) using normal vector? 
I'm using Matlab.I will appreciate every helpful tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably refer to [back face culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling): you can determine, using dot product between the normal vector and the view direction whether the normal faces the viewer (negative dot-product) or faces away from the viewer (positive dot product).

Comment: I thought about  making some condition that delete each point whose  normal vector and the view direction form angle  beyond the section (0, 90). But I dont know which component of normal vector I should use and how to describe view direction.

Comment: @Bartrvncan you specify a point in 3D (x,y,z) where the viewer is standing?

Comment: Opposite the XZ plane. But I don't know specific position.

Comment: @Bartrvn so the viewer is looking along the Y direction? use view vector `[0 -1 0]` and dot-product it with the normals. For this specific view direction it means that you only need to look at the sign of `ny` if it is positive - the point is visible, otherwise it is not.