# Removing hidden points from cloud

Tags: matlab

I want to remove hidden points looking from a view point (V)

```
V=[ xv yv xv omega phi kappa]
```

Cloud has normals:

```
cloud=[ x y z color nx ny nz]
```

- Hidden point= Viewer is at point V and looks at object point 'B'.  Point 'A' is exactly behind 'B' from this viewing angle. Therefore, it should be removed.
  (See figure 2)
  But, if viewer is at point V1 and looks at object point 'B'.  Point 'A' is not behind 'B' from this viewing angle. Therefore, it should be not removed.*
  (See figure 1)
  I know of [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16581-hidden-point-removal/content/HPR.m) post, I found it interesting and tried it but with no example data I don't know how can I use it.

I also know of this post [How to remove hidden points from point cloud using normal vectors (in matlab)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645876/how-to-remove-hidden-points-from-point-cloud-using-normal-vectors-in-matlab) but I cannot understand the answer and it's hard to figure out.

How can I remove double points without using position of viewer and rotation. Please help me in this respect. Any link would be nice.

[image: figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: What is a hidden point without a viewer? To my understanding a hidden point is a point facing away from the viewer.

Comment: "Point B is hidden behind Point A" is equivalent to "The position of the viewer is located on the Ray with origin A and orientation (A-B)". You asked for a solution without using the position of the viewer.

Comment: I vote to close this question, not having a clear definition of intensity values and hidden points allows to many possible answers. I recommend to grab pen and paper, draw a 5x5 grid of points, randomly remove 2 outer and two inner points, assume intensity .5 and try to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but without more details about your naming convention or specific problem, I can only give a general answer. I understand that you have a point of cloud seen under a certain angle, and you're trying to determine the set of points that you can afford not to draw, either because they are behind points that are closer to the camera, or because they are in the "hidden part" of the object under that angle.

The last distinction is key, there are two independent problems that you need to solve:

1. Given a cloud of point, you might want to compute the convex hull of your object, or use other methods to determine it's **outer surface**. The idea is that for representation purposes, if your object is not to be sliced or opened, only it's surface matters. The general problem of finding a surface that fits a cloud of points is hard, so you'll need to add in more constraints specific to your application.
2. Given the outer surface of an object (typically a triangulated mesh), and an angle of view, you might want to decide which subset of points build up the "visible part" of your object. This is the back-face culling problem that the answer to your link mentions. The idea is that given a plane orthogonal to your camera angle (the plane of view) and a certain depth to be calculated, you want to find the set of vertices above or below that plane. This is done quite simply, given a reference point on your plane of view, by looking at the dot-product of the vector linking that reference point to any vertex of your mesh with the camera normal. If positive, the vertex is "hidden" and if negative it is "visible".

Hope this helps.